# Mysql how to sort rows from left to right

Tags: mysql

I have table with field `id`,  `direction`, `parent_id`. There are 2 values `left` and `right`, how can I order them to make something like this:

```
1 row) 1, left, 0
2 row) 2, right, 1
3 row) 3, left, 1
4 row) 4, right, 2
5 row) 5, left, 2
6 row) 6, right, 3
```

I want to order them left to right according to the parent id, I mean for each parent there are 2 rows: left and right. Is that possible?

Comment: can u post the table and some data in www.sqlfiddle.com its unclear what u are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean sort by `parent_id` and then by `direction`?

```
ORDER BY parent_id, direction
```

Comment: No, this will return the *expected 2nd row* in 3rd place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...If every parent_id have 2 direction this may help ...

```
select direction , parent_id from 
(
    select @a:= @a + 1 as a,direction , parent_id from table t,(select @a := 0) a
    ORDER BY parent_id , direction  
) a
order by  case when a = 1  then 1  when a%2 = 0 then a + 1  else a-1 end , parent_id
```